# Angular pages are not loading in any browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

My angular and bootstrap application is not loading pages. I have double checked all hooks but cannot see what's wrong. Here is the [site](http://writers-tryst.ron-tornambe.com/). The enablers, contact and create account buttons are implemented. The js/script.js file contains the controllers. Hopefully, a second set of eyes will help resolve this issue.

Comment: Isn't the link to the website a clear problem statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't set the ng-app directive:

```
<html ng-app="wtApp">
    ....
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Giovani, but now the createAccout is shown above the home page.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work correctly. Thanks again.